# LocalJumpError heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Today I made some changes to my web page, and when I run git push heroku master, it generates the following error.

```
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        LocalJumpError: break from proc-closure
remote:        /tmp/build_061d81ed3e2b67570a905089039000ec/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/inherited_resources-6fa6e5b9d29c/lib/inherited_resources.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Just create some migrations. There were no big changes.

**After running the  comado, did not give me error in the terminal but my page no longer loads, says application error**

```
rails assets:precompile
```

Comment: did you run that migration on heroku?

Comment: @uzaif No, he does not let me upload the changes, always sends me that mistake.

Comment: `LoadJumpError` is occure when you have error with block ,does your code run properly in local machine?

Comment: @uzaif Yes, everything works correctly.

Comment: does this error cause because of your migration?

Comment: @uzaif I do not think so, I do not know if it will be something heroku